# Custom Windows Authentication in IIS through render pipeline module possible?

Tags: .net, authentication, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

From my understanding, [Windows Authentication](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication) in IIS (Kerberos, NTLM) requires that my web server is in the same Windows domain as the domain I am authentication against.

In other words: It is *not* possible (without AD trusts) to have IIS in domain A and authenticate users against domain B.

Having read about the [IIS 7+ request pipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx), and found an [example on how to use Forms Authentication against another domain](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748/en-us), I still have no clue whether Windows Authentication is also able to be "redirected" to my own request pipeline handler.

(The reason I want to use Windows Authentication is so that web browsers in the same domain do not see a login dialog box but are logged in automatically).

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to write a custom IIS request pipeline handler to implement Windows Authentication against a different domain?

Comment: It is possible to write a native module to replace the Microsoft one, but I don't think it would be easy.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks! I've googled a lot but found no commercial solution to simply purchase and configure. Did I missed some vendors?

Comment: There are many workarounds, such as setting up a second site for that untrusted domain. Thus, people go the easy ways than hacking IIS.

Comment: @lexli any suitable keywords to google for those workarounds?